# Updating a row in a Google Fusion Table

Tags: sql, row, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to update a row in a Google Fusion table as per the instructions on [this](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Updating) page with a URL of the following form:

```
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query/?sql=UPDATE<TABLEID>SET<COLUMN NAME>=<NEW VALUE>WHERE ROWID=<ROWIDVALUE>
```

When I enter this into a browser I get a 'File Not Found' message. Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be a general problem with the "old" API. The Trusted Tester API works, though.

Answer (score 4):

Need oauth2 to create token. See details [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/source/browse/trunk/samples/script/ScriptSample.html?r=40) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996487/fusiontables-private-table-with-oauth2)
Then simply add that token to URL

```
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query/?sql=UPDATE<TABLEID>SET<COLUMN NAME>=<NEW VALUE>WHERE ROWID=<ROWIDVALUE>&access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to actual examples and direct guides. I'm tired of being pointed in the direction of reading the entire documentation on something, that's not an answer to the question.  It certainly provides the important context and should be read eventually but I post questions because the guide is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a table, either using the old or the new API, you need to send an authorization header along with the request. More information about authorization can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Authentication